# ImageFactory New Instance Fails

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to access a bitmap saved file and perform ObjectDetection on it. I utilize ImageFactory for this, but creating a new instance fails.

val imageFactory1 = ImageFactory.getInstance()

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Create new ImageFactory failed!
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ai.djl.android.core.BitmapImageFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ai.djl.android.core.BitmapImageFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.imageclassification2-_snYrn7mbGjXlperEzCKWg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.imageclassification2-_snYrn7mbGjXlperEzCKWg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.imageclassification2-_snYrn7mbGjXlperEzCKWg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

Not sure what BitmapImageFactory is, I've never heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

The class **ImageFactory**  can not be found, it looks like you are using the
the [DLJ library](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary), make sure you have proper dependencies

[Djl for android dependencies](http://djl.ai/android/)

```
 dependencies {
    implementation platform("ai.djl:bom:0.20.0")

    implementation "ai.djl:api"
    // TODO: remove djl android package version in 0.21.0
    implementation "ai.djl.android:core:0.20.0"
    runtimeOnly "ai.djl.pytorch:pytorch-engine"
    runtimeOnly "ai.djl.android:pytorch-native:0.20.0"
    runtimeOnly "ai.djl.android:onnxruntime:0.20.0"
}
```